# How to know which client invoke RMI method on the server

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, distributed-computing

I'm developing a system using Java RMI. I've several RMI clients and one RMI server. My system is supposed to be Byzantine Fault Tolerant, so the clients can be malicious (not only crash-stop).

In that sense, I should be able to recognize in the server when a client is invoking duplicated or trying to invoking methods using other clients information (to trap de server and the majority voting). To solve that, I'm using a public/private key shared by client and server. Each client has a unique key to generate and hash and the server will verify the hash. Now, I need to know in the server side which client invoke the method to know which key I should use to verify data.

Is possible to know, on the server, which server are invoking the methods?

Regards and thank you,
Hugo

Comment: Just as a side note/question, How can you achieve Byzantine Fault Tolerant with only one Server?

Answer (score 2):

Use the result of [`RemoteServer.getClientHost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RemoteServer.html#getClientHost%28%29).

Comment: It works! Thank you! I can't vote up because I have less than 15 points :( Thanks you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think the RemoteServer has a method to get the client IP address when someone is invoking a method.

If the IP is sufficient you can look into that.